# software to monitor internet usage on an XP PC? (browser + non-browser)

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy, internet

Is there any (ideally open source) software for Windows that can be used on a PC, to monitor the usage of internet from that PC?   It would need to include both browser and non-browser sources (e.g. a service that sync's calendar to gmail).

So any software on your PC that uses would need to be configured to point to this local internet monitoring software/proxy.  The monitoring software/proxy then would be configured to point to the company proxy server (address, port & credentials).

Things that come to mind that might be close but not really focused on solving this might be perhaps: Charles Proxy, Fiddler 2, SQUID?

The idea would be it could give you a daily/weekly/monthly report of internet upload/download usage on a per program/process/service basis for the PC it is being run on.

thanks

PS The scope is only monitor Internet usage for the PC that the software is running on.  It's just aimed at tracking my own Internet usage at work on my PC from the point of view of the various software I have that does sync to Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this for a specific computer or all computers? You could use a turnkey firewall like smoothwall or related appliance software in front of your proxy (or replace your proxy). That would give you reports based on IP of anything that was going out of your network, often by protocol, for the cost of a small server. Failing that you could use a virtual machine, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a dedicated VM server.

This would also centralize your monitoring and make it more flexible rather than having the hassle of individual monitoring on each machine and taking up resources on each system due to a monitoring program and it would be more transparent to the user(s).

Comment: The scope is only monitor Internet usage for the PC that the software is running on.